# Significant differences to treatment in non-homogeneous dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

My dataset is about forest stands. They are composed of different species and lie in different countries with different climates.

I am working with a model, looking at the impact of different management approaches (e.g. pruning, fertilization, etc) on wood growth.

What I would like to see is if the growth differences achieved with the different management aproaches are significant.

I wanted to try either the Anderson-Darling or the Kologorov-Smirnov test to see if there are significant differences, but I am not sure if they would work for my datasets, as (i) I have the same forests in each sample (although using a different management approach) and (ii) the forests are really different in the first place.

Can you tell me if this is a valid approach and if there would be a better alternative?

Comment: It's commonly not good practice to define the result before you model something. That may lead to biased model generation and selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset consists of paired data i.e. it is data for the same forests but considering different treatments.

With a Wilcoxon signed-rank test it is possible to see if the samples come from populations having the same distribution. It does this by looking at the population mean ranks.